# What does " > sql.txt && sql -h-1 -i sql.txt && del sql.txt" commands mean?

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, sqlcmd

I am debugging some code that builds a SQL command which runs successfully.

However at the end of the query it looks as if the results of the query are written to a text file.

The full query is below

```
echo SELECT DATE,DATETABLE,DATE,APPDATE FROM CTD_ADF WHERE DATE IN (20130911) > sql.txt && sql   -h-1 -i sql.txt   && del sql.txt
```

I assume the `> sql.text` is basically saying create and write the results to a text file called sql.text?

And, at the end `&& del sql.txt` deletes the sql.text file at the end of execution?

But what does the `&& sql -h-1 -i sql.txt` commands do / mean?

I've tried researching the `-h-1 -i` commands but so far have not managed to find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is like using [SQLCMD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx)

> `-h -1` suppresses the column headers, and `-i` specify the input file, which is sql.txt

You can further check the [syntax of sqlcmd Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) see if this is the case.

Comment: ~ excellent information, thank you, I tried to mark your answer up but I don't have the necessary privileges to do so.

Comment: Yes, I know.. But glad this did help